# functioning with objects of word document

Tags: vb6, automation, ms-word

I need to place three objects on my `.doc` in this order:

- `One Picutre;`
- `Some Text;`
- `One Table;`

I recently learned how to place the image where I want (top of the doc).
But now, the table is getting in the middle of the text, how may I set the text with something like `Position Absolute` and then the `Table` below the `text` ?!

My Currently code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim Word_App            As Word.Application
Dim Word_Doc            As Word.Document
Dim Word_Table          As Word.Table
Dim Word_Range          As Word.Range
Dim iCount              As Integer

'Insert the image
Word_App.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
Word_App.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\p\53.jpg", SaveWithDocument:=True
Word_App.Selection.TypeParagraph

With Word_App
   'Here I place some text
End With

'Insert Table
Set Word_Table = Word_Doc.Tables.Add(Range:=Word_Doc.Range(Start:=20, End:=20), NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=4, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed)

Word_Doc.SaveAs FileName:="C:\p\TestandoPicture"
Set Word_Table = Nothing
Set Word_App = Nothing
Set Word_Doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is an example of the result:
[image: Example]

`Notice that:` In my code, I typed the position for my table `Start:=20, End:=20` and it's in the 20th position of character... But i'd like to place it below the text... Wich is the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the text, do a word count on the highlighted text, then use the character count from that to position your table.  Crude but effective.